# Library to convert PDF to DXF

Tags: open-source, library, pdf, c++, document-converter

I'm searching for a library (commercial use required) that I can use for my program to be able to convert PDF documents into DXF files.

I don't seem to be lucky enough with my Google researches. I tried pstoedit but that has a GPL license which won't allow me to use it in my commercial application.

Comment: Do you mean AutoCad DXF files?? What's in the PDFs then? There's plenty of info about [embedding PDFs in AutoCad files](https://www.google.nl/search?q=embed+dxf+in+pdf), but not the other way round.

Comment: PDF may have vector graphics. I need to extract that stuff (suitable to a conversion to DXF).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check out the [LEADTOOLS Document SDK](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/document) to achieve this functionality.

There is the [RasterCodecs Class](https://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v19/dh/co/leadtools.codecs~leadtools.codecs.rastercodecs.html) that can load the PDF file (and other document formats) as SVG using the [LoadSVG method](https://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v19/dh/co/leadtools.codecs~leadtools.codecs.rastercodecs~loadsvg(string,int32,codecsloadsvgoptions).html) and then you can use the LEADTOOLS Vector SDK to take the SVG file and convert it to DXF.

Here is a forum post on the LEADTOOLS Technical Support Forums that has a sample project showing how to achieve this:

[How to Load PDF as SVG then save to DXF](https://www.leadtools.com/support/forum/posts/t11170-HOW-TO--Load-PDF-as-SVG-then-save-to-DXF)

Here is the relevant information from the post:

> This sample will load a PDF (or any of the Document Formats we currently support) as an SVG file and save it to a temporary file, then load the temporary SVG file and save it as a DXF file (or any of the Vector Formats we currently support).
>
> The application is written in Managed C++ (CLR Console Application). 
>   It uses our .NET interface to load the Document Format as SVG and save the SVG file to a temporary file on disk.
>
> It then uses our C interface to load the SVG file from disk and save it as a vector format, in this case: DXF.

Disclaimer: I am an employee of the company that wrote this library